# SQLalchemy custom String primary_key sequence

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For the life of me, I cannot think of a simple way to accomplishing this without querying the database whenever a new record is created, but this is what I'm trying to do with sqlalchemy+postgresql:

I would like to have a primary key of a given table follow this format:
`YYWW0001`, `YYWW0002` etc. such that I see values like `20010001`, `20010002` such that the last four digits are only incremented within the given week of the year, then resetting when a new week or year is entered.

I'm at the limit of my knowledge here so any help is greatly appreciated!
In the meantime, I am looking into `sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence`.

Another thing I can think to try is creating a table that has let's say 10,000 records that just have a plain Integer primary key and the actual ID I want, then find some sort of 'next' method to pull from that table when my Core object is constructed? This seems less than Ideal in my mind since I would still need to ensure that the data portion of the id in the table is correct and current. I think if there is a dynamic approach it would best suit my needs.

so far my naiive implementation looks like this:

```py
BASE = declarative_base()
_name = os.environ.get('HW_QC_USER_ID', None)
_pass = os.environ.get('HW_QC_USER_PASS', None)
_ip = os.environ.get('HW_QC_SERVER_IP', None)
_db_name = 'mock'

try:
    print('Creating engine')
    engine = create_engine(
        f'postgresql://{_name}:{_pass}@{_ip}/{_db_name}',
        echo=False
    )
except OperationalError as _e:
    print('An Error has occured when connecting to the database')
    print(f'postgresql://{_name}:{_pass}@{_ip}/{_db_name}')
    print(_e)


class Core(BASE):
    """
    This class describes a master table.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'cores'
    udi = Column(String(11), primary_key=True, unique=True) # <-- how do I get this to be the format described?
    _date_code = Column(
        String(4),
        default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%U")
    )


BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
date_code_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%U")
cores_from_this_week = session.query(Core).filter(
    Core._date_code == date_code_now
).all()
num_cores_existing = len(cores_from_this_week)
new_core = Core(
    udi=f'FRA{date_code_now}{num_cores_existing+1:04}'
)

session.add(new_core)

session.commit()

session.close()
engine.dispose()
```

Comment: You should not be using a string as the primary key. Make an integer column, name it `id`, make that the primary key. Then have this string column as an alternative key if you wish.

Comment: ok, That makes sense. I suppose I was just making sure this particular key is unique since it will be used to track some product test data I am working on.